# passwordless ssh (ssh-copy-id) not working, if the remote user's home folder is under /home2 instead of /home

Tags: linux, ssh, selinux

I am setting up passwordless ssh from a client to a server.

I have two users, called `user1` and `user2`. Both on the client and on the server, `user1` has a home folder at `/home/user1`, i.e. the default folder when you create an account using the command `useradd user1`.

Both on the client and on the server, `user2` has a home folder at /home2/user2. This was done by creating the user with the command  `useradd -m -d /home2/user2 user2`. The reason for this is, I mounted `/home2` on a larger 16TB disk and wished to give user2 more storage at its home folder.

I set up according to all recommendations. and I set `/home2`, `/home2/user2`, and `/home2/user2/.ssh` to the correct 700 permissions.

I found that after all these, passwordless ssh works for `user1` from the client to the server, but does not work for `user2`. It still asks for password after I applied `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` with `user2` on the client to the server.

It puzzles me. Does it mean the home folder for `user2` has to be `/home/user2` and cannot be in other locations (e.g. `/home2/user2`)? Unfortunately I just got 100GB for the `/home` folder and I want more space for `user2`.

In response to requests for further information, I have just looked up into the server ssh log (`/var/log/messages`) after I issued an auto login from the client. The log says this:

```
Jan 20 09:42:55 SERVER dbus-daemon[2502]: [system] Activating service name='org.fedoraproject.SetroubleshootPrivileged' requested by ':1.39048' (uid=977 pid=2794759 comm="/usr/libexec/platform-python -Es /usr/sbin/setroub" label="system_u:system_r:setroubleshootd_t:s0") (using servicehelper)
Jan 20 09:42:55 SERVER dbus-daemon[2502]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.fedoraproject.SetroubleshootPrivileged'
Jan 20 09:42:58 SERVER setroubleshoot[2794759]: SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/sshd from read access on the file authorized_keys. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l 6b9fec5b-5b03-460b-8199-393d5863256b
Jan 20 09:42:58 SERVER setroubleshoot[2794759]: SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/sshd from read access on the file authorized_keys.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall_labels (83.8 confidence) suggests   *******************#012#012If you want to allow sshd to have read access on the authorized_keys file#012Then you need to change the label on authorized_keys#012Do#012# semanage fcontext -a -t FILE_TYPE 'authorized_keys'#012where ...`
```

Please help me sort this out.

Comment: Is the `authorized_keys` file set up properly for `user2` regardless of the home directory? Does the SSH server give any errors about it in the logs?

Comment: What does "not work" actually mean? Does it fail due to authentication issues, or due to permission issues, or is there some issue with starting the user's login shell on the remote host? What do you see if you run `ssh -vv` to try to connect?  Is the user with the `home2` home directory able to log in locally?

Comment: "not working" meaning it asks me to input password, despite me having completed the two steps of setting up passwdless ssh: (1) `ssh-keygen` (2) `ssh-copy-id` from the client to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which Linux distribution is used at the server, and does it use SELinux (check with `sestatus`)?

If it does, you would also need to do something like:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t home_root_t '/home2'
semanage fcontext -a -t user_home_dir_t '/home2/[^/]+'
semanage fcontext -a -t user_home_t '/home2/[^/]+/.+'
restorecon -rv /home2
```

to assign proper SELinux labels to `/home2`, the actual user home directories below it, and the users' files under `/home2/<username>` directories.

(The example labeling applies to RHEL9: older releases may have slightly different SELinux label structure. If unsure, use `ls -ldZ /home; ls -lZ /home` to verify the existing labels under `/home` and adjust the labels on `/home2` to match.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My CentOS is 8 stream.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your four lines of commands, and all issues now resolved!

Comment: Your situation was basically identical to the issue I had to solve recently. Whenever you are using RHEL or other SELinux-enabled distribution and place e.g. user home directories in a non-standard location, you must also update the SELinux labelling rules to cover that location, or else the standard system services (or any services that have non-trivial SELinux rules applied to them) may have trouble accessing files in that location.